# Is it possible to read a protobufs encoded message without using code generation?

Tags: protocol-buffers, avro

When I am decoding protobuf encoded data, I use `parseFrom()` method which is available in the code generated by `protoc`.

What I want to know is, is there a way to load protocol buffers data into some kind of a generic object, and read data from it using field names or tag numbers, without using code generation?

This is available in Avro with `GenericRecord`. What I want to know is, whether there is a similar capability in protobuf too.

Comment: You might want to try Protobuf's reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it

1. Compile the `proto` file into a `desc` file

   ```
    protoc --descriptor_set_out=point.desc --include_imports point.proto
   ```
2. Load the desc file.

   ```
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream("point.desc");
    DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorSet descriptorSet = DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorSet.parseFrom(input);
    DescriptorProtos.FileDescriptorProto fileDescriptorProto = descriptorSet.getFile(0);

    Descriptors.Descriptor messageDescriptor = Descriptors.FileDescriptor
            .buildFrom(fileDescriptorProto, new Descriptors.FileDescriptor[0])
            .findMessageTypeByName("Point");
   ```
3. Use the loaded descriptor to decode data.

   ```
    DynamicMessage dynamicMessage = DynamicMessage.parseFrom(messageDescriptor, encodedBytes);

    int x = (int) dynamicMessage.getField(messageDescriptor.findFieldByName("x"));
   ```